# What are some reasons ASP .NET startup would be so slow

Tags: asp.net, performance, .net-4.0, startup

I have Visual Studio 2010 and a pretty large web application project running on IIS 7. Startup for the web application is over a minute (75 seconds). I've attached ANTS to it and very little of the 75 seconds is my code. Most of it seems to be something like CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment and BuildManager stuff. Now I know that ASP .NET will compile dynamically the first time but I certainly don't expect it to compile for that long. Why could I be experiencing this problem and what are some ways I can try to fix it or try to better understand what is taking so much time. Aksi the CPU utilization doesn't seem to be that high. I have an awesome machine.

The problem with the 75 second startup is that for developers working on this, everytime they make a change they have to wait this 75 seconds.

I am using .NET 4.0

**EDIT**
I ran Microsoft Network Monitor on my machine to see if there was anything suspicious going on the network. There wasn't as far as I can tell though i wasn't sure what to look for (I am familiar with network monitor though so I did have an idea of what I was doing). I tried to run it in release build and though it may have improved the performance a little bit its not really significant

**EDIT**
I have SQL Session state. As far as i can tell, the connection string is pointing local. For some reasons though, when examinning ANTS, i'm getting a lot PollLockedSessionCallback on many threads. The function seems to be called over 70 times. Does this help at all?

Comment: Have you tried running Wireshark or Fiddler on the box to see whether it's talking to some slow network resources?

Comment: are you absolutely sure that is compile time and not executing of the methods of Global.asax already? Did you split all logic into layers like business logic, Data access, service layers etc or is your web application containing everything?

Comment: I will try that now. Anything i should be looking for? There is a lot of stuff going on my network!

Comment: I had bad experiences with lots or RESX files (e.g. 50 ASPX pages and each in 30 languages = 1500 RESX files to compile). Try [Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) whether you are seeing lots of files being accessed/compiles.

Comment: If this is your issue, too, I can tell you how I solved this easily :-)

Comment: Please tell us anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try building the application in `release mode`. You can set this in the Build tab of the properties window. You might also consider pre-compiling when publishing the application before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access anything via a network share at startup?  If so, bring those resources local for startup comparison.